# QueryDict is empty, after received from the POST request

Tags: django, post, axios

I used axios to send a POST request, here is my code:

```
register: function (){
                      console.log("register start");
                      if (this.password !== this.confirmPassword) {
                          alert("The Password IS DIFFERENT THAN CONFIRM PASSWORD!");
                      } else {
                          console.log("register start");
                          const data = {
                              firstname: this.firstname,
                              lastname: this.lastname,
                              username: this.username,
                              email: this.email,
                              password: this.password,
                              confirmPassword: this.confirmPassword
                          }
                          console.log(data)
                          axios.post("/register", data)
                              .then(res => {
                                  alert("Register Success!");
                                  console.log(res);
                              })
                              .catch(error => {
                                  console.log(error);
                              })
                          }
                      }
```

And here is the code for received the POST request:

```
def register(request):
    try:
        # receive POST request, queryDict object
        if request.method == "POST":
            print("Post Request Received")
            user_info = request.POST
            print(request.body)
            print(user_info)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error", e)
        return render(request, "error.html", context=e)

    return render(request, "register.html")
```

However, I keep received an empty QueryDict but I did comform that the return type is Json and it does received something, here is the output: `Post Request Received b'' QueryDict}`

I had found a method, which is replicate the POST request and decode it. Here is the code:

```
        if request.method == "POST":
            print("Post Request Received")
            request_data = request.body
            user_info = request_data.decode("utf-8")

            print(user_info)
```

Here is the output, after the changed:

```
Post Request Received
{"firstname":"First Name","lastname":"Last Name","username":"username123","email":"username123@gmail.com","password":"12345678","confirmPassword":"12345678"}
[25/Mar/2023 16:07:07] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 5347
Post Request Received
------WebKitFormBoundarycXOVuwbkiaqZTvQy--

[25/Mar/2023 16:07:07] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 5347
```

And the problem is that I coundn't modify or take a more specific data for example "username" from it. I used `print(user_info["username"])`, however, the output showing `context must be a dict rather than TypeError.`

I expect that I can receive the data from the POST request like this: `{"firstname":"First Name","lastname":"Last Name","username":"username123","email":"username123@gmail.com","password":"12345678","confirmPassword":"12345678"}`
And can able to take out a specific data from the dict. For example can able to print out `print(user_info["username"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer for my question. In the data of the Vue.js, I removed dataForm and using data dict instead.

```
const data = {
                              firstname: this.firstname,
                              lastname: this.lastname,
                              username: this.username,
                              email: this.email,
                              password: this.password,
                              confirmPassword: this.confirmPassword
                          }
```

If I using the normal procedure to receive the POST request, there are two request will be received simultaneously. And here is the output of the POST request:

```
Post Request Received
{"firstname":"First Name","lastname":"Last Name","username":"username123","email":"username123@gmail.com","password":"12345678","confirmPassword":"12345678"}
[25/Mar/2023 16:07:07] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 5347
Post Request Received
------WebKitFormBoundarycXOVuwbkiaqZTvQy--

[25/Mar/2023 16:07:07] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 5347
```

The type of the request is **String**! Thus, we have to covert String to Json type(using Json.loads). However, the `Error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` will been printed out. This error meaning that because of the second part of the Post Request is not a proper json type(dict), it is normal String("------WebKitFormBoundary") instead, which cannot be parse as the Json type. In order to deal with this problem, I am using a if statement to filter the second part of the POST request, here is my code: `if request.body.decode('utf-8')[0] == "{":`. And now, the code can successfully been converted to Json type.
Here is my code for the whole process:

```
    try:
        # receive POST request, queryDict object
        if request.method == "POST":
            # For filter WebKitFormBoundary POST request string
            if request.body.decode('utf-8')[0] == "{":
                response = request.body.decode('utf-8')  # response is a string
                response = json.loads(response)       # response is a json object(dict)
                print(response)

                first_name = response["firstname"]
                last_name = response["lastname"]
                user_name = response["username"]
                email = response["email"]
                password = response["password"]
                confirm_password = response["confirmPassword"]

                return render(request, "register.html")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error", e)
        return render(request, "error.html", context={"error": e})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be available in request.POST you need to send your data as a `FormData`

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('firstname', this.firstname);
...

axios.post("/register", formData)
  .then(res => {
      alert("Register Success!");
      console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
  })
}
```

To fix your current way of doing things, you need to parse the request.body:

```
import json
user_info = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
print(user_info["username"])
```

Also, the context in the `render()` should always be a dict, so the correct way to show the error is:

```
...
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error", e)
        return render(request, "error.html", context={"e": e})
```

Comment: First of all, I am appreciate of your response, thanks you. After I changed my code as the example you gave me, the new error occurred as `Error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. And it isn’t meaning that there is a none JSON type data been post?